# Table stick to top of the page, how to remove it?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Please have a look at this image:

[image]

I have a table that is 4 pages long. The tableheader is stuck to the top of a page, and then that whole page is empty. The table continues on the next page.

How do I get it so that the tablecontent starts right after the tableheader, as it normally would?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: can you please press ctrl+* and provide another picture?

Comment: ctrl+* ? That does absolutely nothing at all

Comment: I should display control characters, I wanna see them!

Comment: Have you tried table tools->Layout->Properties->Positioning opetions?

Comment: Ctrl+shift+8 was the combination I needed :) Here's your image: http://piclair.com/data/lgjz8.jpg I have tried to delete those characters in the left-bottom but then the tableheader will jump to the previous page :(

Comment: at this bad situations I convert table to text using Layout->Data->Convert To Text with Tab character and then recreate my table using Insert->Table->Convert Text To Table Using Tab character, Must of times this will fix my problems! Try it.

Comment: Right-click on the table handle and click "Table properties" go to the "row" tab and uncheck the "Allow row to break across pages" and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @K.Rmth: I think you mean ***check*** the "Allow row to break across pages" option.  In any case, toggle it.

Answer (score 5):

Hi go to table tools layout, properties and then go text wrapping - none and click OK, the table will move down from being right at the extreme top edge

Comment: This is the correct solution! Thank you. Only 2h of my life, gone!

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all table contents
2. Navigate to "Layout tab" (Near "Search Tab")
3. Go to "Properties" (Below the "File tab")
4. Click the "Properties tab", under the table properties box that appears, find the tab written "Positioning" and click it.
5. Select the vertical position from `-1` to `Top` and click OK.
6. Proceed with your job relaxed!

Comment: ***step0***: fix the formatting of this answer ...

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution! After struggling with this for like 3 days I finally figured it out. I had to share it with the internet. Anyway, click the table so everything is highlighted, go to the "Layout" tab at the top, and click "Table Properties" all the way to the left. In the pop up box, under "Text Wrapping" click "Around". Then click "Positioning..." and in the next pop up box, under "Vertical", set "Relative to:" to "Margin" (or "Paragraph" might work too). BADDA BING!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one. it solves my problem.
Select table, right-click, then select table properties. Under Alignment, select center and select "None" for text wrapping. Hope this might help.

Disclaimer: Not a professional in this field, just based on actual experience shared for a reason to help.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click to place your cursor within the table
2. On the ribbon in the Table Tools *Layout* tab, click **Properties** in the Table group
3. On the *Table* tab, click **Positioning** to open the Table Positioning dialog box
4. In the Vertical section, click the Position drop down and select **Top**